# golang webapp with LDAP

Tags: go, active-directory, ldap

I try to build web application using Active Directory authentication. I also need to get email address of a user. I have a function that can get email  address.
Where and how should I use the function to get email in mainHandler()?

main.go

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", auth.BasicAuth(mainHandler))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func mainHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/main.html")
    if err == nil {
        tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
    }
}
```

auth.go

```
type Handler func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)

// BasicAuth - handler wrapper for authentication
func BasicAuth(pass Handler) Handler {

    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        username, password, ok := r.BasicAuth()
        err := ValidateAD(username, password)
        if err != nil || !ok {
            realm := "Please enter your corporate key and password"
            w.Header().Set("WWW-Authenticate", `Basic realm="`+realm+`"`)
            // w.WriteHeader(401)
            http.Error(w, "authorization failed", http.StatusUnauthorized)
            return
        }
        pass(w, r)
    }
}

var ErrEmptyUserOrPass = errors.New("Username or password cannot be empty")
var conn *ldap.Conn


// ValidateAD validation based on Active Directory
func ValidateAD(user, passwd string) error {
    if user == "" || passwd == "" {
        return ErrEmptyUserOrPass
    }
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
    var err error
    conn, err = ldap.DialTLS("tcp", "ad.something.com:636", tlsConfig)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    domainPrefix := "ad\\"
    err = conn.Bind(domainPrefix+user, passwd)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

// GetLDAPEmail returns email address for given username and password
func GetLDAPEmail(user, password string) (string, error) {
    if err := ValidateAD(user, password); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    searchBase := "CN=" + user + ",OU=OU1,OU=OU2,OU=OU3,DC=ad,DC=something,DC=com"
    searchFilter := "(&(samAccountName=" + user + "))"
    searchRequest := ldap.NewSearchRequest(
        searchBase, // The base dn to search
        ldap.ScopeWholeSubtree, ldap.NeverDerefAliases, 0, 0, false,
        searchFilter,     // The filter to apply
        []string{"mail"}, // A list attributes to retrieve
        nil,
    )
    sr, err := conn.Search(searchRequest)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    email := sr.Entries[0].GetAttributeValue("mail")
    return strings.ToLower(email), nil
}
```

Comment: You can just call `GetLDAPEmail` in your `mainHandler` if you send it a username and password

Comment: How can I get username and password to pass to GetLDAPEmail()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your functions and handlers are wired, I do not see a whole lot of "clean" options to pass state back from `BasicAuth()` to the `mainHandler()` per request.

If you are open to the idea of changing the way you setup your handlers, here is a skeleton structure which you can expand to fit your needs:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type User struct {
    Name     string
    Password string
}

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.Handle("/", &User{})
    s := &http.Server{Addr: "localhost:8080", Handler: mux}
    log.Fatal(s.ListenAndServe())
}

func (u *User) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //Pull out the username and password
    u.BasicAuth()
    fmt.Println(u.Name)
    fmt.Println(u.Password)
    //The rest of your main handler
}

func (u *User) BasicAuth() {
    //This is to demonstrate the ability to pass state
    //Edit this to fit your needs
    u.Name = "user"
    u.Password = "pass"
}
```

The `User` struct implements the ServeHTTP function, effectively implementing the `http.Handler` [interface](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler) which opens up the option of adding it to a multiplexer which in turn helps maintain the username and password per request. Although the methods receive a pointer type you could change it to better suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks. Today I discovered that I can also get auth data from r.Header["Authorization"] :)